# "Linear algebra done right", example 1.37, sum of subsets not clear

Tags: linear-algebra

Just a quick question on example 1.37 of Axler's 3rd edition of *Linear Algebra Done Right*.

We're given the following:

---

Suppose $U$ is the set of all elements of $\mathbf{F}^3$ whose second and third coordinates equal $0$, and $W$ is the set of all elements of $\mathbf{F}^3$ whose first and third coordinates equal $0$:

$U = \{(x,0,0) \in \mathbf{F}^3 : x \in \mathbf{F} \}$ and $W = \{(0,y,0) \in \mathbf{F}^3 : y \in \mathbf{F} \}$.

Then

$U+W = \{(x,y,0): x, y \in \mathbf{F} \}$

---

I understand the sum of subset definition (1.36), but is this saying that $(x,y,0) \notin \mathbf{F}^3$ ?

Comment: No... the "$\in \Bbb F^3$" was merely omitted.  $U+W = \{(x,y,0)\in\Bbb F^3~:~x,y\in\Bbb F\}$.  You have that $(x,y,0)$ is a triple of elements, all three of which are elements of $\Bbb F$ and as such by definition the triple is an element of $\Bbb F^3$.  When context is clear certain things can be left out.